# Build a geographical map from triangle points based on distance

Tags: geometry, triangulation, trilateration

I have 5 {x,y} points randomly placed on a grid

Each of the points **do not know** the {x,y} coordinates of the other points

Each of the points **do know** the distance of each of the other points from their {x,y} position

Each of the points exchanges this distance information with every other point

So every point knows every distance of every other point

Using this distance information every point can calculate (by finding the angles) triangles for every other point using itself as a reference point

Example, point 1 can calculate the following triangles:
1-2-3,
1-2-4,
1-2-5,
1-3-4,
1-3-5,
1-4-5,
and using the distance data recieved from the other points it can also calculate
2-3-4,
2-3-5,
2-4-5,
3-4-5

I would like to build a map of the location of every other point relative to a single point

How should I go about doing this? I am asuming it would be some kind of triangulation algorithm but these mainly seem to compute the location of a point from three other points, not the other way around where the other points {x,y} coordinates are discovered based on only the distance information.

I have tried plotting the two possible triangles for every 3 triangle points and then rotating them on a fixed known point to try and align them, but I think this avenue will end up with too many possibilities and errors

Ultimately I would like every point to end up with {x,y} coordinates of every other point relative to itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know the distance from one point to every other, `dij`. Thus, point 2 lies in a circumference of center point 1 and radius = d12. Point 3 lies in a circumference of center point 1 and R=d13 and it also lies in another circumference of center point 2 and R=d23.

See this picture:

[image]

I've set point 2 in X-axis for simplicity.

As you see, point 3 is on the intersection of two cicrcumferences centered at P1 and P2. There is a second intersection, `P3a`. Let's choose the one that is upwards and continue.

For `P4` we can use three circumferences, centered at P1, P2 and P3. Again we get two solutions.

The same process can be done with the rest of points. For `Pn` you have `n-1` circumferences.

I'm sure you can find the maths for circle-circle intersection.

Some remarks must be observed:

1) The construction is simpler if you first sort the points by distance to `P1`.

2) Not all distances generate a solution. For example, increase `d13` an there's no intersection between the two circumferences for `P3`. Or increase `d14` and now the three circumferences don't intersect in just the two expected points `4` and `4a`.

3) This fact can be overworked by considering the average of intersections and the distance from each solution to this average. You can set a *tolerance* in these distances and tell if the average is a solution or else some `dij` is wrong. Since two solutions are possible, you must consider two averages.

4) The two possible triangulations are symmetric, over X-axis in the case I've drawn.

The real solution is obtained by a rotation around `P1`. To calculate the angle of rotation you need the `{x,y}` coordinates of another point.

Comment: That's great, many thanks.  If a single or multiple points were to move whilst P1 stays the same, would I be able to determine which of the two possibilities is correct?

Comment: @billysdomain Symmetry is always there until you use the coordinates of two more points. This means, until you have a triangle whose coordinates are known in advance, and you use this triangle to solve both symmetry and rotation.

Comment: So the only possible way of solving the symmetry is to introduce a known point, any movement any of the points make in any sequence cannot help?

Comment: Any movement is just new distances, and thus a new triangulation. You are again at the start line. Without known points symmetry still stands.